# Simple html dom parser - nothing happens

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I'd like to parse a HTML site via HTML dom parser. My simple code is:

```
<?php
    require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file('http://google.de/');
    echo $html->find('img',0)->getAttribute('src');    
?>
```

I've got the `simple_html_dom.php` file on my server but when I access the PHP file nothing happens. Blank screen! I tried many different codes, I think the problem is not the code. Do I have to install dom-parser on my server or do I have to have a certain version?

Comment: Tag the question PHP.

Comment: ...I see that I´ve got php version 4.4.8. is that the reason?

Comment: Run the installer of same version on your server, and look under extensions, see if the extension is installed.

Comment: I updated the server to php 5 now it works :) Thx.